# Omite el primer registro y guarda en la B.D. a partir del segundo. 2.-Subo archivo .CSV pero si al mismo archivo le cambio el nombre no lo admite

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente código en php el cual genero una subida de archivos `.CSV` los registros deben guardarse temporalmente en la B.D. y lo hace, pero los guarda a partir del segundo registro y el primero siempre lo omite.

¿Por qué? no hallo mi error.

Mi segunda pregunta es que: me dieron un archivo prueba, llamado "ejemplo.csv" con el cual he hecho todas mis pruebas pero ayer le cambié el nombre al archivo por: "Entrada1.csv" y lo lee pero no guarda ningún registro dentro de la B.D.

```
//---------------------------------CODIGO PHP


<?php
    // -- Limpio la tabla para nuevas inserciones
    mysql_query('TRUNCATE tef.archivo;'); //Limpia registro tabla

            if(isset($_POST['uploadBtn'])) {
                $fileName        = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
                $fileTmpName     = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];


                $fileExtension  = pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $allowedType    = array('csv');

                if(!in_array($fileExtension,$allowedType)){

                    ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            ARCHIVO INVALIDO
                            </div>

                    <?php 
                        }

                else {
                    $registros = array();

                    if (($fichero = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {

                        $nombres_campos = fgetcsv($fichero, 0, ",", "\"", "\"");
                        $num_campos = count($nombres_campos);

                        // Lee los registros
                        while (($datos = fgetcsv($fichero, 0, ",", "\"", "\"")) !== FALSE) {


                            for ($icampo = 0; $icampo < $num_campos; $icampo++) {
                                $registro[$nombres_campos[$icampo]] = $datos[$icampo];
                            }


                            $registros[] = $registro;
                        }

                        fclose($fichero);
                ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">

                            <?php       
                                echo "Archivo: \n". $fileName.$registros[$i][$nombres_campos[0]]. "\n  Leidos " . count($registros[$i]) . " registros <br>";
                            ?>      
                        </div>
                <?php   

                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($registros); $i++) {

                            $query =  "INSERT INTO tef.archivo (numero_proveedor,nombre_proveedor,monto_pago)
                            VALUES ('".$registros[$i][$nombres_campos[0]]."','".$registros[$i][$nombres_campos[1]]."','".$registros[$i][$nombres_campos[2]]."')";
                            $run   =  mysql_query($query);          
                            }
                    }   
                }

            }   

?>



  <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Seleccione un archivo </h4>
<!--FORM -->        
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        </div>    
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" name="myFile" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <input type="submit" name ="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-md">

        </div>
        </form>



    enter code here
    </div>  

    </div>



</body>
<footer class="footer">

</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Karina, bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Este sitio funciona **por preguntas**, o sea, no es válida formular dos preguntas en una, sobre todo cuando los motivos sean diversos, como es este caso. Aunque sea el mismo programa, lo que hace que tu archivo sea leído a partir de la segunda fila no tiene nada que ver con que el cambio de nombre del archivo no funcione. Recomendaría que dejes el primer problema en esta pregunta y que plantees una nueva pregunta con el problema del cambio de nombre del archivo, dando los detalles que puedan ayudar en ese problema en concreto.

Comment: El primer problema puede deberse a esta línea: `for ($icampo = 0; $icampo < $num_campos; $icampo++) {  $registro[$nombres_campos[$icampo]] = $datos[$icampo];
 }` la cual parece estar escrita para ignorar la primera línea (que es en realidad la línea `0`), que a veces contiene los encabezados del archivo, no los datos en sí. En el bucle, al aumentar la variable `$icampo` saltas la 1ª línea. Prueba el código así: `for ($icampo = -1; $icampo < $num_campos; $icampo++) { $registro[$nombres_campos[$icampo]] = $datos[$icampo];}` ahí debería recoger los datos que hay en la 1ª línea.

Comment: @A.Cedano Eso no es correcto la tercera expresión del `for` se evalúa al final de la iteración no al principio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por el consejo de las preguntas. En relaida no sabia que era por pregunta. pero Gracias lo corregire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de que se salte la primera línea viene dado por qué `fgetcsv()` avanza el puntero. Es decir que cada vez que llamamos  `fgetcsv()`  sobre sobre el puntero abierto por `fopen` este avanza.

Para reiniciar el puntero podemos utilizar `fseek()` justo antes del `while`, es decir:

```
if (($fichero = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // obtener columnas y avanzar puntero
    $nombres_campos = fgetcsv($fichero, 0, ",", "\"", "\"");
    $num_campos = count($nombres_campos);

    // reiniciar el puntero
    fseek($fichero, 0);

    // Lee los registros
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($fichero, 0, ",", "\"", "\"")) !== FALSE) {
        // body while
    }
}
```

En cuanto a lo del nombre, el Script que muestras esta diseñado para trabajar solo con archivos `.csv`, si quieres permitir algún otro tipo de extensión deberías añadirla al array `$allowedType`

Comment: Hola Xerif muchas gracias tu respuesta me ha sido de gran ayuda y ha corregido mi problema de la primer linea.